# Linux delete egrepped lines

Tags: regex, linux, file, grep, tcpdump

I pass file to my egrep expression (tcpdump log), then I want to delete all matched lines

Code example:

```
cat file | tr -d '\000' |egrep -i 'user: | usr: ' --color=auto --line-buffered -B20
```

How can I delete all matched lines now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -v flag

> ```
>  -v, --invert-match
>          Selected lines are those not matching any of the specified patterns.
> ```

```
cat file | tr -d '\000' |egrep -iv 'user: | usr: ' --color=auto --line-buffered -B20 > newfile
```

Comment: It deleted something, but grepping with the same regex on new file still does show me some entries (I believe it should now)

// Deleting line formatting did the job for me - thanks!

Comment: Case of `UUOC`. A single `sed` can do the job of both `tr + grep` and moreover bonus of inline file editing.

Comment: That is just the bonus part

Comment: along with the accidental file corruption ;)

Comment: You probably don't know about inline editing and saving original as backup using `-i .bak` option

Answer (score 0):

You can do all that using `sed`:

```
sed -iE '/use?r: /d; s/\x0//g' file
```